# send, recvfrom, threads, "Broken Pipe" and SO_RCVTIMEO bug

Tags: c, multithreading, send, recv, epipe

I have a server coded in C++ running on ubuntu 10.04, currently in production, which exhibit a weird bug.

#### Context :

Each client connecting to the server has one socket and 2 threads

- 1 thread for writing to the socket,
- 1 thread for reading from the socket.

The socket is configured via `::setsockopt` with `SO_RCVTIMEO` of 10 seconds.

Each `::send` on the socket has flag `MSG_NOSIGNAL` set
(each `::recvfrom` also, but it seems it should have no impact)

#### Bug :

I have some evidence (but not 100% sure) that the following scenario may occur rarely :

- `::recvfrom` is called and block until either data is present or timeout is reached
- `::send` is called and the write on the socket triggers an error, returns `EPIPE` (Broken Pipe) error
- Bug : `::recvfrom` is still blocked, and will never return, somehow ignoring `SO_RCVTIMEO` option

Does the above scenario makes some sense to you ?

#### Metrics :

The bug happens approximatively every week. During a week, there is approximatively :

- 20K sockets used
- 30M `::recvfrom` called
- 60M `::send` called

Should I rather use the timeout feature from `::select` ? (supposing that the timeout implementation would be different from the `SO_RCVTIMEO` one)

Thanks a lot for any idea on this matter !

Comment: Please add a language tag.  This looks like C++?

Comment: Does your metric observe cases when recvfrom times out as expected? That is, do you have a proof that SO_RCVTIMEO works in your server?

Comment: select() or even epoll() is indeed a more standard way to handle socket communication.

Comment: The language is C++, but it could be C.

Comment: SO_RCVTIMEO works : we use it for a ping system similar to what you found in MMO. If we don't get a ping from the client in less than 10 seconds, we close the connection.

Comment: select or epoll won't prevent the fact that I need to send data asynchronously and at any moment. Then would select or epoll unblock if send "detects" a broken pipe ? At least for the old select, it depends on how the timeout is implemented, but is it different to SO_RCVTIMEO which seems to be a facility somehow ?